# unable to parse value of selected item in a listview object

Tags: vb.net, sockets, listview, vb.net-2010, listviewitem

OK my dilemma is the following, whenever i try to parse a selected item in a listview object it will not pass that value to a function, i know if i use .text or .tostring it will work fine parsing the selected item, but the parsed item will be used as a socket connection, an example of a value selected `127.0.0.1:5688` and for ended the error string cannot be converted to system.net.socket.sockets is trigger when debugging the app if i use listview1.items.item(I).text or tostring

Here is the problematic part

```
    For I As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
    If ListView1.Items(I).selected = True Then
    send(RichTextBox2.Text & vbNewLine, ListView1.Items.Item(I).Tag)
    End If
    Next
```

and here is the function where the parsed value is supposed to be passed along

```
 Private Sub Send(ByVal msg As String, ByVal client As Socket)
    Dim sendBytes As Byte() = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg)
    client.BeginSend(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnSend), client)
End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, did you assign a Socket object to the Tag property?  It sounds like not.  Why would you expect a String contain an IP address and port number to magically become a Socket?  If you want a Socket then create a Socket.

Comment: this is server/client application with reverse sockets connections, all the connections are async and  have multiple clients connected at the same time, now lets say i try to send a command to one of the clients, first i have to pick what connected client i want to command, and such client has already a established socket connection. Now the problem is that all the clients are added to a listview box and selected from there.

Comment: it was working fine with listbox but i wanted to add icons to each connected client so i used the listview instead as recommended by many people on this site. the only way that i can select the item from my listview is using a .tag instead of .text or string. Any ideas how to work that around?

Comment: As I already said, if you want a Socket then create a Socket.  Either create a Socket and assign that to the Tag of each item or else create a Socket with the IP address and port number when you get the String from the Tag.  The String is not going to transform into a Socket of its own accord.  You have to create the Socket yourself.

Comment: Thank You, i manage to fix the issue with someone else question :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304195/vb-net-asynchronous-multiclient-server-properly-removing-clients-from-the-list

Comment: here is the fix: Dim clientIP() As String = client.LocalEndPoint.ToString.Split(":")
        Dim items(1) As String
        items(0) = clientIP(0)
        items(1) = clientIP(1)

        Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(items, imagelist1.Images.Count - 1)
        lvi.Tag = client
        ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)